# What does the client_id and client_secret do in laravel passport?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-passport

I think i know what they do but i want some clarification on this as I am a bit confused.

My understanding is:

- `Client_id`: is the id of the device or location of application when logging in?
- `Client_secret`: secret code to access access tokens and refresh tokens?

I am basing these assumptions on how the database table looks like.

Also, I have read the documentation but I still don't have a clear understanding on how they are supposed to be used/implemented.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found out the answer:

- `Client_id`: is the application client, if you have one client to manage other services and it is based on Laravel's Grant implementation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#issuing-access-tokens).
  Each client implementation is for that application you make, with making use of access tokens and/or refresh tokens
- `Client_secret`: Is the secret password key that is generated, making another barrier for an attacker to access the data. If someone gains the `access_token`, they next need to get the `refresh_token`, then the `client_id` and get the `client_secret`.